# Cannot access static files of WordPress docker container over HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, apache, docker, ssl, proxy

I am trying to create a WordPress container over HTTPS, I have Apache running on the VPS and using it as a proxy to route requests to WordPress container.

I've managed to access the container to load WordPress Installation page over HTTPS but CSS/JS files won't load because they are requested over HTTP I don't know why the redirect is not working with these files, I did other websites like this.

[Here is a print of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/814sN.png)

If I access the files on 'http://example.com/wp-admin/css/install.min.css?ver=5.2.2' the redirect [works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfmKE.png) (print of the css file over HTTPS after accesing the link above)

This is the redirect for 80 to 443 on the domain.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the proxy on 443:

```sh
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example.com
        ProxyPreserveHost On

        ProxyPass / http://172.20.0.100/ 
        ProxyPassReverse / http://172.20.0.100/


        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile /fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /privkey.pem
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

WordPress container listens only on port 80

Here is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  wpdb:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
        MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
        MYSQL_USER: wordpres_admin
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
     - wpdb
    image: wordpress:latest

    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.100
    restart: always
    environment:
        WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: wpdb:3306
        WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpres_admin
        WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: pass
volumes:
    db_data: {}

networks:
 default:
   external:
     name: router_default
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Have you enabled SSL module at your Apache?

Comment: yes, it is enabled, as you can see in the hyperlink i can access the resources alone over https but it's not working when I'm accessing the page

Comment: Set your site url settings to `https` as well in `/wp-admin/options-general.php`, otherwise it will try to access the JS and CSS assets via http, which is blocked by your browser's security policy.

Comment: @Capsule, what do you mean by site url settings?
do you mean to enable SSL on WordPress website from docker container ?

Comment: No, I'm talking about the wordpress settings that you define when setting it up, or via  the options if already setup. If you don't have access to the admin interface because it doesn't load properly, you can manually change the values in the wp_options table of the database.

Comment: @Capsule tried to change http to https in the wp_options table ,but that would cause an infinte redirect

Comment: That's not normal. Did you change it in both `siteurl` and `home` fields?

Comment: @Capsule, Yes, both of them, i watched the requests very carefully, seemed like the host  received the request on https ://example.com,then the the proxy was accessing http: //172.20.0.100 of the container and then WP would redirect the received request back on the value i changed in the table wich is https: //example.com and here is the loop.
But i found the solution after googling around some more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution, looks like WP is already configured to be used through a proxy with SSL and there is no need to change anything in the WP container or WP settings, all that needs to be done is to rewrite the header of the request with :

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
```

The updated proxy config looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com

    <IfModule headers_module>
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
    </IfModule>

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / http://172.20.0.100/ 
    ProxyPassReverse / http://172.20.0.100/


    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile /fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

For more info: https://wordpress.org/support/article/administration-over-ssl/#using-a-reverse-proxy
and https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/97005/setting-x-forwarded-proto-under-apache-2-4